# Rails 3.2 Active_presenter rubygem - is it dead

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I note rubygem 'Active_presenter' by originally by James Golick hasn't been maintained for some time now and appears to be incompatible with Rails 3.2.

Does any one know if work is being done on this **most valuable gem** to make it compatible.

And if so, any idea when?

Regards
Ross

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Github project](https://github.com/jamesgolick/active_presenter/pull/3) there is some work going on but nothing that has been published yet.

You might try pulling the code, updating it and using your [local copy as a Gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/). Then you could later issue a pull request.